# XSD: unique attribute values within node

Tags: xml, xsd, unique

I have XML data with parent-child relationships and want to prevent (per XSD), that the child is its own parent.

The XML:

```
<categories>
        <category id="1">
            <name>cat1</name>
        </category>
        <category id="2">
            <name>cat2</name>
        </category>
        <category id="5" parent_id="5"> <!-- should not validate!-->
            <name>subcat5</name>
        </category>
</categories>
```

So the constraint is, that id and parent_id need to be different. I tried some stuff with `<xs:unique>` but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't express these type of relationship (aka restriction) between attributes in XSD. You can just specify that the value of `parent_id` should be selected from one of `id` values of `category` element (using KEY and KEYREF elements), but you can not specify that having the same value between two attributes is invalid.